# Android parse two array into ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

my `ListView` extends from `ListFragment` and after define subClass for customAdapter extends from `BaseAdapter` could not parse two array to layout elements.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/txt1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/txt2"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

`setListAdapter` function:

```
public class ResivedSMS extends ListFragment {
.
.
.
public ResivedSMS() {
    testArray1 = new String[] {
            "1111111111",
            "2222222222",
            "3333333333",
            "4444444444",
            "5555555555",
            "6666666666",
    };
    testArray2 = new String[] {
            "AAAAA",
            "BBBBB",
            "CCCCC",
            "DDDDD",
            "FFFFF",
            "GGGGG",
    };
}
.
.
.

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ViewResivedSMSDetailes customListView = new ViewResivedSMSDetailes(getActivity(),testArray1,testArray2);
        setListAdapter( customListView ); //call the method if listFragment

    }

.
.
.

class ViewResivedSMSDetailes extends BaseAdapter
{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private String[] values1;
    private String[] values2;
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt1;
        TextView txt2;
    }

    public ViewResivedSMSDetailes(Context context,String[] values1,String[] values2)
    {

        this.values1=values1;
        this.values2=values2;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return values1.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index) {
        return values1[index];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if(convertView ==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, null);
            holder.txt1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
            holder.txt2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.txt1.setText(values1[position]);
        holder.txt2.setText(values2[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**UPDATED POST:**

list_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/txt1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/txt2"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

logCat Result:

```
08-24 14:48:03.245      851-851/ir.tsms E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at ir.tsms.ResivedSMS$ViewResivedSMSDetailes.getView(ResivedSMS.java:105)
```

ResivedSMS.java:105 is:

```
holder.txt2.setText(values2[position]);
```

Comment: Looks fine. Show the code where you're instantiating the adapter. Also note that you need the arrays to be of the same size so there are enough items to show.

Comment: @user3249477 i'm using `setListAdapter( customListView )` in `onCreate` function and for one array i dont have problem. but i can not parse two array into `ListView`

Comment: Paste the layout used in the adapter. `list_fragment`

Comment: Re you sure that `testArray1` and `testArray2` are non-null and of the same size?

Comment: @SimonMarquis post updated. i'm paste `testArray1` and `testArray2`. i dont have problem in array and problom is only can parse one array

Comment: So try to debug manually. On the getView method, test if `holder.txt2` is null

Comment: @SimonMarquis `holder.txt2` must be get item from `values2` thats not null

Comment: My question was, is this variable null? `if(holder.txt2 == null){Log.e("","NULL");} else { LOG.i("", "NOT NULL");}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what it looks when you are inflating the view in the `getView()` callback method you are not setting the `ViewGroup` parent.

Try changing the following line:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, null);
```

To:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, parent,false);
```

And I would suggest creating a shared class of both of the views, and have a single data set and not two data sets to avoid index out of bounds exceptions.